# Change initial View Controller of Master-Detail-Application

Tags: ios, storyboard, viewcontroller, launch, master-detail

I created a new iPhone project on a Master-Detail-Application. As I need a login before, I added at the **storyboard a new ViewController**, checkmarked "**is initial View Controller**" and assigned the new created **class LoginViewController** to this ViewController.

*Furthermore but not relevant (in my opinion), i created a segue and connected it from the ViewController to the NavigationController (of the Master-Detail-Template).*

The **AppDelegate.m** was changed to launch the new controller at startup:

```c
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    /* // Old Master-Detail-View-Controller
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    MasterViewController *controller = (MasterViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
     */

    (LoginViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    return YES;
}
```

This will end up in the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
reason: '-[UICollectionViewController loadView] loaded the "Qn5-Rj-iPA-view-IRE-eP
-ILZ" nib but didn't get a UICollectionView.'
```

I have as well tried this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];

    self.window.rootViewController = loginViewController;   //Set the view controller
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Resulting in a similar error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'
```

Where is my mistake?

What I do not get is, where the hell the **UICollectionView** in the error message comes from. I did never create one or add one??

[image: Storyboard]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My `LoginViewController` inherits by mistake form `UICollectionViewController` instead of `UIViewController`. I fixed that and it works.

This explained the **strange errormessage** which i did not understood in the first place. As always **the truth is in the sourcecode**. Rechecking helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything to load view controllers in the AppDelegate. As long as your stroyboard is the one that is loaded in project settings, it should load automatically.

Comment: I tried this as well, but this throws as well an error. As the code **expects a topViewController** which the new **viewController** isn't - see the first comment in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**. As well I just tried with only **return YES;**, but this didn't work as well. Will recheck.

Comment: Besides doing my fix, I had to remove everything from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and just `return YES;`. Now it works.